# how to load a DOM document in the current document?

Tags: javascript, jquery

this is sadly a stupid question. However, if someone can point me in the right direction I would appreciate it. I am trying to learn a bit JQuery, and have written the following;

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
var test = $.get( "http://www.facebook.com", function() {
   alert( "Load was performed." );
});
</script>
</head>
</html>
```

I believe that test now contains a DOM object of the Facebook.com-website. How can i now write/load the content onto document (my current file)? if I insert document.write(test) it then prints object object but not the object(s) content.

Comment: Why do you believe that?

Comment: you are just sending a request and displaying an alert,but not storing returning data

Comment: @Andrew Barber, I assumed so from what is written at the w3school-website on DOM manipulation.

Comment: This is one of the problems with that site. It gives out some bad information at times.

Comment: @hotGopher Why not look at examples on jQuerysite or SO?  W3Schools is notoriously bad as a source for code examples.

Comment: @andrew. It may be that I misunderstand greatly what they say too.

Comment: @mike. I am looking on different sites, but has found that the best way to understand what it says on these is to first find something i want to do, and adopt what I believe the sites says and then ask question here on stack. From this "tweak" on the sites information I get, in my opinion, a better understanding of what they try to teach. The illustrating code on the sites are often "safe" and made to work and thus makes me potentially lazy if I do not examine it line by line.

Comment: hotGopher, do you know about [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

Comment: @beetroot. No, i can't say that I do.

Comment: Suggest you read BenjaminGolder's answer below.

Comment: @beeroot. Yes, i see now that there are several things I need to think about. Thank you all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var test;
$.get( "http://www.facebook.com", function(data) {
       test = data;
       alert( "Load was performed." );
 });
```

Now your test contains something and you can put it inside a div,for example if you have a div like:

```
<div id="content"> </div>
```

Use this:

```
$("#content").html(test);
```

Take a look at the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) for more examples

Answer (score 3):

jQuery's [`.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) function is used to retrieve data using [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)). Generally, ajax is used to grab data or fragments of websites, not to load entire websites.

So there's a few problems:

1. Due to something called ["Access-Control-Allow-Origin"](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/43639/why-is-the-access-control-allow-origin-header-necessary), Facebook won't let you load their main webpage using AJAX. Due to security concerns, you can't just load anyone's website. However, [many websites](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+api) have [API's](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/howto/jquery) that let you [grab data](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/) from them
2. Even if you were getting something back from the `http://facebook.com/` url, you're not doing anything with the data that would be returned. See Selman22's answer for an example of what to do with data you've received from an ajax call.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have this div:

```
<div id="fb"> </div>
```

You could do:

```
$.get( "http://www.facebook.com", function(data) {       
   alert( "Load was performed." );
   $("#fb").html(data);
});
```

I'm asssuming you are running in an env that doesn't have the Same Origin Policy (for example Phonegap App).

If you're running in a typical browser, due to that policy it won't be possible to make the ajax call to facebook.com

Cheers

Comment: i think selman22 answered my question first with an example. However, mentioning the same origin policy in your answer was very good.

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 options if you want to have Facebook show up on your site.

Te first is use an iframe, however I am sure that they will have security in place to break out of frames.

The other is do web scraping, however this requires server side coding such as PHP, Node, etc

Here is a node example
http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/easy-web-scraping-with-nodejs